# Update to kernel 5.3.0-40, no wifi - ubuntu 19.10, intel ac 9560

Tags: wireless, kernel, 19.10

2 thinkpad, x1 yoga 4th, 
    A is with Ubuntu 19.10, kernel 5.3.0-18, 
    and B is with Ubuntu 19.10, kernel 5.3.0-29,
both wifi (Intel ac 9560) work fine.

Updated these 2 laptops(`sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`), 
then kernel updated to 5.3.0-40, but WiFi icon disappeared, cannot connect internet with WiFi.

Installing drivers, or updating `/lib/firmware`, does not work.

But when booting to old kernel version(5.3.0-18 / 29), WiFi works.

How to enable WiFi Intel ac 9560 on Ubuntu 19.10 with 5.3.0-40 kernel?

dmesg errors:

```
[    0.837843] tpm tpm0: tpm_try_transmit: send(): error -5
[    0.837846] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead    
[    1.327684] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA8005:00: failed to retrieve report from device.    
[    2.290041] irq 31: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)    
[    2.290077] handlers:
[    2.290079] [<0000000042ddd934>] tis_int_handler    
[    3.069570] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA8005:00: failed to retrieve report from device.    
[    4.009236] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.    
[    4.009314] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:    
[    4.009317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, coudmesg errors:nt: 169840516    
[    4.009319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0    
[    4.009320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7EB08CBE | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT              
[    4.009322] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD34B1C42 | trm_hw_status0
[    4.009323] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2A83D5B1 | trm_hw_stadmesg 
errors:tus1   
[    4.009324] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFE3AE448 | branchlink2   
[    4.009325] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x91D0D28B | interruptlink1   
[    4.009326] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0867EB65 | interruptlink2   
[    4.009327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBCAF51DF | data1   
[    4.009328] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF406D8B4 | data2   
[    4.009329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB9E671E4 | data3   
[    4.009330] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x71635431 | beacon time   
[    4.009332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0EF3B01B | tsf low   
[    4.009333] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7A06466F | tsf hi   
[    4.009334] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48166D12 | time gp1   
[    4.009335] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7DA5A66B | time gp2   
[    4.009336] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF8A87C4B | uCode revision type   
[    4.009337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCF185A20 | uCode version major   
[    4.009338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x82643A8B | uCode version minor   
[    4.009339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3FA9F91A | hw version   
[    4.009340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD03FB09D | board version   
[    4.009342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6328571D | hcmd   
[    4.009343] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD7C8B92C | isr0   
[    4.009344] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA7167883 | isr1   
[    4.009345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x812F083B | isr2   
[    4.009346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF12501FA | isr3   
[    4.009347] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEB193E2C | isr4   
[    4.009348] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB2E1167E | last cmd Id   
[    4.009349] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA2FD022E | wait_event   
[    4.009350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x21CBC8B9 | l2p_control   
[    4.009351] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FFF1333 | l2p_duration   
[    4.009352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08AE50F2 | l2p_mhvalid   
[    4.009353] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x72195CAC | l2p_addr_match   
[    4.009354] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2CE4DAA5 | lmpm_pmg_sel   
[    4.009356] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x23653546 | timestamp   
[    4.009357] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCEA83EB8 | flow_handler   
[    4.009388] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:   
[    4.009389] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7   
[    4.009390] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT   
[    4.009391] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1   
[    4.009393] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2   
[    4.009394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1   
[    4.009395] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2   
[    4.009396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1   
[    4.009397] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2   
[    4.009398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | umac data3   
[    4.009399] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major   
[    4.009400] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor   
[    4.009401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005D2C | frame pointer   
[    4.009402] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer   
[    4.009403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd   
[    4.009405] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg   
[    4.009421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:   
[    4.009424] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE   
[    4.009427] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION   
[    4.009429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE6C42F2D | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION   
[    4.009432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION   
[    4.009435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x127104E1 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION   
[    4.009438] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xACAED0E2 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN   
[    4.009440] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2EE283C1 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID   
[    4.009443] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5CDB8CB | FSEQ_CNVR_ID   
[    4.009446] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP   
[    4.009451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP   
[    4.009456] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | 
CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM   
[    4.009491] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | 
CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR   
[    4.009524] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c94, CPU2 
Status: 0x3   
[    4.009525] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110   
[    4.009535] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error   
[    4.022490] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your kernel log (`dmesg`) when you boot with `5.3.0-40` ?

Comment: Yes, there are errors. Please kindly find the logs here: https://pan.baidu.com/s/1oRkAd9KYx42OP6rBbgzZzg, download code: tame

Comment: There is a bug in 5.3.0-40, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1864188

Comment: I managed to hammer a solution without changing kernel (keeping 5.3.0-40). You may see it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1867026. (still, the correct answer is above)

Comment: dragosht, Jeremy31 and Tcarreira, thank you for your kindly reply.